# How do I publish my Windows desktop application?

Tags: windows

*I am not sure if this is the correct location for this question.
If not please let me know and I will remove it...*

I created my own stand-alone Windows desktop application to manage personal notes. I know there are plenty of these out there, but I created this one according to my own preferred specifications, with emphasis on privacy and efficient search caps.

I was wondering if there is an easy way to publish it, free of charge, so other people can see if it is useful also for them.

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider platforms like GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, SourceForge.

You can provide binary releases as well as source code, so that people who like transparency will be able to see what your application is really doing and to build the application on their own.

Comment: Thanks @mentallurg, 
The above are open-source services. In my case the code is already written. Do I need to share the code in order to publish the executable?

Comment: @PazO: No, you don't need to share the source code at all. But it would help to get trust. Without sharing it can take much more efforts to convince users to user your application. I'd suggest that you order a certificate from some trusted CA and sign your binaries at least. This will give a bit more trust.